# SQL merging rows with least amount of queries

Tags: mysql, sql

My database system is pretty easy. I have a table with the users, and a table with 'guesses'. My site has logos, and a user can guess the name of each logo. There is a unique relation between the `logo_id` and the `user_id`. Here's the guesses table-structure:

```
|| id | user_id | logo_id | guess | guess_count | guessed | level | time ||
```

Now, when a user visits the page and isn't logged in, a user is made with the `session_id` and all the guesses and stuff are stored in the same structure. So the only difference is in the `user`-table.

Now I want the user to be able to login and keep whatever he/she just did. Of course, if the logged in account already has the logo as guessed, this shouldn't be altered. But when the logged in account has a logo as not-guessed, the `guess_count` of the session user should be added to the logged in user `guess_count`. Also the `guessed` should be updated. It should only do this if the time of the edit was more recent, but I think it's safe to assume that the session-guesses are more recent.

Now how I would do this, is loop through all the logos from the logged in id first where `guessed = 0`, then for each result do a query again to add the `guess_count` and store the `guessed`, then remove all the ones found from the session-id, then loop through all the old ones with the session-id and change the `user_id` to the one of the logged-in-user. Now, this is a ton of queries, so there must be a more efficiënt way.

Any thoughts? Sorry for the wall of text & bad explanation, databases are not my best thing.

Comment: You could probably do this in a single stored proc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have no idea how to start stored procedures, I've just written it out in a few queries, but it's okay I guess.

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT logo_id, guess_count, guessed, guess FROM guess WHERE user_id=:id GROUP BY logo_id");
$STH->bindParam(":id",$loginuser['id']);
$STH->execute();
while($row = $STH->fetch()){
    if($row['guessed'] == 0){
        $STH2 = $DBH->prepare("SELECT guess, guess_count, guessed FROM guess WHERE logo_id=:logo_id AND user_id=:id");
        $STH2->bindParam(":logo_id",$row['logo_id'],PDO::PARAM_STR,20);
        $STH2->bindParam(':id',$_SESSION['login'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $STH2->execute();
        $row2 = $STH2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($row2){
            $STH3 = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE guess SET guess_count=guess_count+:guess_count, guessed=:guessed, guess=:guess WHERE logo_id=:logo_id AND user_id=:id");
            $data = array('guess_count'=>$row2['guess_count'],'guessed'=>$row2['guessed'],'guess'=>$row2['guess'],'logo_id'=>$row['logo_id'],'id'=>$loginuser['id']);
            $STH3->execute($data);

            $STH3 = $DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM guess WHERE logo_id=:logo_id AND user_id=:id");
            $STH3->bindParam(":logo_id",$row['logo_id']);
            $STH3->bindParam(':id',$_SESSION['login']);
            $STH3->execute();
        }
    }else{
        $STH2 = $DBH->prepare("DELETE FROM guess WHERE logo_id=:logo_id AND user_id=:id");
        $STH2->bindParam(":logo_id",$row['logo_id']);
        $STH2->bindParam(':id',$_SESSION['login']);
        $STH2->execute();
    }
}
$STH = $DBH->prepare("UPDATE guess SET user_id=:login WHERE user_id=:session"); // update all entries that are new from session
$STH->bindParam(':login',$loginuser['id']);
$STH->bindParam(':session',$_SESSION['login']);
$STH->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry havn't used mySQL in donkey's years, but here's an example of the stored procedure in SQL Server: Hopefully someone can help with the MySQL syntax, or you can infer it from the SQL below

```
CREATE PROC MergeGuesses
 @UserSessionId INT,
 @UserId INT
AS

 --where the userId has already a guess for the logo update it
 UPDATE gusr
 SET gusr.guess_count = gusr.guess_count + gses.guess_count,
     gusr.guessed = gses.guessed
 FROM Guesses gusr
 JOIN Guesses gses ON gusr.logo_id = gses.logo_id
                   AND gusr.time > gses.time  -- more recent
 WHERE gusr.user_id = @UserId
 AND gses.user_id = @UserSessionId
 AND gses.guessed = 0 --not yet guessed

 --where there is no guess for the user yet - just update the userId
 UPDATE gses
 SET gses.user_id = @UserId
 FROM Guesses gses
 LEFT JOIN Guesses gusr ON gusr.logo_id = gses.logo_id
                        AND gusr.user_id = @UserId
 WHERE gses.user_id = @UserSessionId
 AND gusr.user_id = NULL -- there is no guess for the userId

 --finally delete any rows for the sessionId that are left
 DELETE FROM Guesses 
 WHERE user_id = @UserSessionId
```

Comment: I've never heard of stored procedures, I'll look a little more into it!

Comment: Heres a decent looking tutorial on mySQL stored procedures. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-stored-procedures/ As to the PHP code - it should just be just the one call to the stored procedure (the creation of the stored procedure should be done directly to the database, not in PHP code) eg see the end of this example: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures/